# Mockito - Depth of the mocking when main class contains lot of other classes?

Tags: java, object, methods, mockito, callstack

New to mockito. I am still trying to understand how this works.

For instance, if I mock a class, does it automatically mock all the classes inside that class?

```
  class Bank {
     Customer cust;
     cust.deposit(102, CHECK);
  }

  class Customer {
     Account acct;
     public deposit(int amount, Type t) {
         return account.getLimits( t );
     }
  }

  class Account {
    AccTypes types;
    public getLimits(Type t)  {
      int res =  types.getAccountType(t);
      return res;
    }
  }

  class AccTypes {
    pulic getACcountTypes( Type t){
       return something;
    }
  }
```

1. If I mock `Bank`, does it automatically mock `Account`,`Customer` and `AccTypes` as well?
2. How do I test the `deposit()` method? (It has to eventually reach `getAccountTypes` in `AccTypes`)
   (code please, with explanation).

Note that its a very simple (actually pseudo code). So may not be a perfect java code. But this is just to give you an idea what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: You don't show enough code. "code, please" :p

Comment: Your `Bank` example isn't valid Java code.

Comment: I fail to understand why. Its a simple code, may not be real world. But its simple enough to imagine realworld scenarios.

Comment: I understand object creation code is missing. But it gives you an idea what I want to do.

Comment: Mockito doesn't mock classes. It creates mock instances of a class. So if you create a mock Bank instance, you'll get a mock bank, not a mock Account.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A mock will only implement the same non-private methods as the class or interface you mock. It won't contain any references to any others of your objects, even if the class you mock has references.

To unit test the behavior of the `deposit()` method you would create a mock for all dependencies of `Customer`. The only dependency is `Account` so let's mock it:

```
 Account accMock = Mockito.mock(Account.class);
 Mockito.when(accMock.getLimits(Type.SOME_TYPE)).thenReturn(500);
```

Now whenever anything calls `accMock.getLimits()` with `Type.SOME_TYPE`, it will return 500. If it is called with any other parameter, a default value is returned (`0`, `false` `null`, depending on the return type).
Next we create the object to be tested and set the account field to our mock:

```
 Customer customer = new Customer();
 customer.setAccount(accMock);
```

Call the method to be tested, i.e. `deposit()`:

```
 customer.deposit(100, Type.SOME_TYPE);
```

Now verify the behavior of the method. We expect that it calls `getLimits()` with `Type.SOME_TYPE` and nothing else:

```
 // verify that getLimits() is invoked for Type.SOME_TYPE
 Mocktio.verify(accMock).getLimits(Type.SOME_TYPE);
 // verify that no other method is called on accMock
 Mockito.verifyNoMoreInteractions(accMock);
```

Comment: Awesome! Exactly what I wanted to know!

Comment: How about Utility classes. Do I need to mock them as well if I need to use them?

Comment: That depends on the complexity of the utility class. Sometimes it's easier to mock them and return a constant, well-known value. However, if they are tested well and don't do much, you would probably leave them alone. What you would probably never mock are classes that contain basically getter/setter only and have no further logic, i.e. they just store some values/references.

Answer (score 0):

I may be misunderstanding your question, but when you mock Bank with Mockito and call said mock, you are no longer calling the implementing logic in the Bank class, and so there is no reason Mockito would mock out those dependant classes.

If you wish to return a mocked class from an invocation to Bank, then you can setup your Bank mock to return what you want for the specified invocation, otherwise there is no need to create mocks for those other classes.

E.g.

```
@Mock
private Bank bankMock;

when(bankMock.getAccount().thenReturn(mock(Account.class));
```

Comment: So I create a mock for Bank with mock(Bank.class). I need to call deposit. So I need to mock Customer before I can call and even before the Customer, I need to mock Account, etc? Apologize if the question is not clear.

Comment: @KevinRave No, I think you are confused.  If I create a mock of Bank then I am no longer calling any functionality actually implemented in the Bank class, I am only calling the mock.  This mock allows me to control what should be returned for any call to the mock as well as verify and see that certain calls have been made against the mock.  THe real question here is, why are you creating the mock of Bank, what are you trying to do?

Comment: Bank is my Webservice class and Deposit is my Web service method. It has dependency heirarchy like the Bank class (Account, Customer, etc)